# Auto buy virtual product by product id / user id in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I was wondering if there is possibility (function, hook) to auto buy virtual products from specific category / price (free), knowing id of product and customer?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please learn what questions are accepted by following the Ask a Question instructions (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should investigate what WooCommerce does out of the box by reading their docs. If WooCommerce doesn't offer this and there is no plugin for it, then you will need to write your attempt and post it on SO when/if you have trouble.

Comment: Thanks Christina, i was hoping that tags will do the job for me ;) I have searched documentation and stack for the answer but ended up with nothing.

Comment: Well you can make a url https://yourdomain.com/cart?add-to-cart=3‌​600 (where 3600 is your product id) and then use a url shortener and stick in emails or wherever. – Christina 35 mins ago